# Calculating difference between times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set with 4 (relevant columns): unique id, user_id, time_stamp, event. Unique id is the primary key, user_id can be repeated, time_stamp (datetime) is taken when an event occurs, event is either a) push notification (push) or b) user opening app (open).

It can look like this:

```
id    user_id    time_stamp    event  count it?
 1        1          10         open
 2        1          23         push   -good
 3        1          28         open 
 4        1          38         push   -bad
 5        1          65         open   
 6        1          85         push   -good
 7        1          89         open   
 8        1          28         push   -bad
 9        2          38         push   -good
10        2          45         open
11        2          46         open
```

I am trying to figure out if my push notifications are useful. To do so, I need to see if a user opens the app within 20 minutes of a push notification. I will count this as a "successful push" whereas all other pushes wouldn't be successful. So far I've had the idea to inner join the table on its self, but am having an issue with duplicated rows. For example, we would get false positives with ids 4 because only id 3 should be counted.

```
  SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM table WHERE row = 'open') a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE row = 'push') b 
  ON a.user_id = b.user_id) WHERE a.time_stamp - b.timestamp < 20;
```

Comment: so because 3 is open action and show that the push is already useful, you dont want to count 4?

Comment: With my original query, id 4 was being counted towards the the push at id 2. We just want to see if our pushes bring users into the app.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have multiple records for the same user_id I presume you want to take the latest 'open' time_stamp and compare this with the latest 'push' for each user?

If so I think the following does what you want (needs a tidy up but should do the trick):

```
SELECT et4.User_id, ts1, et3.User_id, ts2
FROM 
(SELECT et1.user_id, max(et1.time_stamp) as ts1 from eventtable as et1 
where et1.event = 'push' 
group by et1.user_id
) as et4
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT et2.user_id, max(et2.time_stamp) as ts2 from eventtable as et2 
where event = 'open' group by et2.user_id) as et3 
ON et3.user_id = et4.user_id
WHERE ts2 -ts1 < 20
```

Basically, select the latest push for each user and join this to the latest open for that user, then calculate the difference in the timestamp.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is super helpful. One more thing: what if I have a user_id that has two push/open events under the same user_id? In your query, we would only get one set user_id.

Comment: Glad to help. The query will pick up the latest 'push' and the latest 'open' for each user. So it won't analyse multiple push/open events for the same user (sounds like you may need it to). It may also not be ideal if there is one 'push' followed by multiple opens as it only looks at the last 'open'. From what you say it might be better to select each 'open' and then find the corresponding next 'push' (note **next** not last). Maybe expand the original question with a bit more detail about what you need now you have this query as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.time_stamp, t1.event,
       t2.id, t2.time_stamp, t2.event     
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 
   ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.event = 'push' AND  t2.event = 'open' AND 
      t2.time_stamp > t1.time_stamp AND t2.time_stamp - t1.time_stamp < 20
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t3 
   ON t3.user_id = t2.user_id AND t3.event = 'open' AND 
      t3.time_stamp > t1.time_stamp AND t3.time_stamp < t2.time_stamp
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
```

**Output:**

```
id, user_id, time_stamp, event, id, time_stamp, event
=====================================================
2,  1,       23,         push,  3,   28,        open
8,  2,       28,         push,  10,  45,        open
9,  2,       38,         push,  10,  45,        open
```

**Note:** You need an additional `LEFT JOIN` if you need to filter out record with `id = 8`.

Comment: This *feels* overly complex - but I haven't had my morning coffee yet, so maybe I've missed something